# Dynamic Fields and/or Artificial Methods

Tags: java, dynamic, methods, field

I work with a dynamic `Dataset` model, which (in short) takes in attributes and stores them in a `Map` like this...

```
Dataset dataset = new Dataset();
dataset.setAttribute("name", "value");
```

...for later recovery, like this...

```
String value = dataset.getAttribute("name");
```

...and that has worked wonderfully for my purposes. But now I'm in a place where I'd like to use a templating engine to dynamically generate HTML. In the template, it's not ideal for me to do a lot of `${dataset.getAttribute("name")}`. It would be rather nice if I could create artificial methods whenever something was added to a `Dataset`. For instance, if I did this...

```
dataset.setAttribute("name", "value");
```

...I'd like to be able to retrieve it like this...

```
String name;
name = dataset.name;
//or
name = dataset.getName();
```

...but so far I haven't been able to pull it off. What approach might I take here? Is it even doable?

***Edit:***

I understand that Velocity offers [Property Lookup Rules](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#propertylookuprules) to try to resolve `dataset.name` to `dataset.get("name")`, and that's great, but I need to know how to achieve this in the case that Velocity *isn't* the target as well.

Answer (score 1):

See http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#propertylookuprules

If your method was named `get(String attribute)` rather than `getAttribute(String attribute)`, you could use the same syntax as for regular properties. So, either refactor your class, or add an additional `get` method that does the same thing as `getAttribute`, or transform your object into a `Map`, which has a `get` method.

Comment: I appreciate this functionality of Velocity, but what about other cases which *don't* include Velocity?

Comment: Then see the other answers, or use real, type-safe, encapsulated, refactorable Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic Spring proxies with AOP technology or CGLib proxies. AOP could be used to describe getters like this : `execution(public * com.bla.YourClass.get*())")`

Comment: One thing that makes this tricky is that `Dataset` is a class of which there are (potentially) hundreds of instances floating around, all with completely different and unrelated attribute sets.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have generated POJOs dynamically with Objectweb's ASM.  This has the benefit that the underlying fields are type safe and much more efficient (esp for privative values)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, it's fairly common for template engines for Java to support both

- getters/setters of the form `getAttribute`, and
- implementation of the Map interface

Before you spend too much time looking for a more generic solution (assuming the above won't be supported like it is in Velocity), it's probably worth taking a look at the other engines to see if any of them don't support it. If all your possible targets do, then you're probably fine relying on it.

*I'm a big fan of making sure you actually have a problem before you spend the time to solve it.*